# Comments in JSF pages and configuration files after compilation

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, comments, facelets

I'm interested when I compile JSF page in Netbeans what happens with the comments into the JSF pages and the faces-config.xml file? Are they preserved or they are deleted by the compiler. If they are preserved can I delete them somehow? 
I know that comments in java beans code are deleted by the compiler but I'm not sure about the JSF pages.

Answer (score 6):

For JSF pages you can use the following context parameter in `web.xml`:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The config files are not processed.

Comment: Yes but this will only disable the comments into html pages but will compile the JSF pages with comments. I noticed that I can compile the WAR packages using custom commends. Is there a command which will tell to Netbeans not to include any comments into the WAR packets?